# Fatal error: Class '' not found while migrate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a column in my database however on my classe is created :

My class Name is add_meta_to_cities_table.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddMetaToCitiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('meta_desc');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
    }
}
```

Just as precision I've ran before `composer dump-autoload`.

When I try to run `php artisan migrate` I'm ending up with this error ?

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Table' not found

Where could this come from ?

Comment: What is your filename for this migration?

Comment: have you run `composer dump-autoload` before trying to migrate?

Comment: Just updated question and yes I've run `dumpautoload` before

Comment: None of that code uses a class called `Table` directly. Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for a detailed stack trace of that error.

Comment: Have you included the `doctrine/dbal` dependency in your composer.json? It's required to make changes to schema. `composer require doctrine/dbal`

Comment: The usual formatting for the migration filename is a follows: `YYYY_MM_DD_000000_create_some_table.php` Maybe try it like that or delete the migration entirely and new it up via artisan.

Comment: @ceejayoz there is no trace of log dated to tooday.. is there a reason for that ?

Comment: @JustinOriginBroadband Yup I tried it already

Comment: @Stephan-v Yes that solved it ! But I tough the first part was generated while composing the migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual formatting for the migration filename is a follows:

```
YYYY_MM_DD_000000_create_some_table.php
```

Maybe try it like that or delete the migration entirely and new it up via artisan. It should be automatically generated in this format when you new it up via artisan:

```
php artisan make:migration create_some_table
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I just would like to use shorthand numeric prefixes (like `00_`, `01_`and so on) to compress file name, but unfortunately it broke the migration process.